# Split a Map<String, List<Item>> into Two Sperate Maps with Overlapping Keys Based on Items

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently split a map into two maps. The original map looks like the following, but is much larger:

```
val sourceMap = <Map<String, List<Item>> = mapOf(
   "key1", listOf(Item(owned: Boolean = true), Item(owned: Boolean = false)),
   "key2", listOf(Item(owned: Boolean = false), Item(owned: Boolean = false)),
   "key3", listOf(Item(owned: Boolean = true), Item(owned: Boolean = true))
)
```

I want to split this maps into two maps, that associates the key to all the "owned = true" items in one map and "owned = false" items into the other. Which would look like:

```
val ownedMap = Map<String, List<Item>> = mapOf(
   "key1", listOf(Item(owned: Boolean = true)),
   "key3", listOf(Item(owned: Boolean = true), Item(owned: Boolean = true))
)

val unOwnedMap = Map<String, List<Item>> = mapOf(
   "key1", listOf(Item(owned: Boolean = false)),
   "key2", listOf(Item(owned: Boolean = false), Item(owned: Boolean = false)),
)
```

Edit: Ideally the answer will allow for all sorting to happen in one pass of the original `sourceMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that might help.

First, we create two maps where we will add the resulting sorted values. After that, we iterate over the sourceMap. SourceMap contains values in the form String, MutableList.

Next, we iterate over the list of items. And if the item has an owned parameter with value true, we add that item to ownedMap, otherwise to unOwnedMap.

```
val ownedMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Item>>()
val unOwnedMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Item>>()

sourceMap.forEach { (key, list) ->
    list.forEach { item ->
        if (item.owned) {
            ownedMap.addToListInMap(key, item)
        } else {
            unOwnedMap.addToListInMap(key, item)
        }
    }
}

fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, MutableList<V>>.addToListInMap(key: K, value: V) {
    if (this[key] != null) {
        this[key]?.add(value)
    } else {
        this[key] = mutableListOf(value)
    }
}
```

You can also write without an extension function. Then it will look like this:

```
val ownedMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Item>>()
val unOwnedMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Item>>()

sourceMap.forEach { (key, list) ->
    list.forEach { item ->
        if (item.owned) {
            if (ownedMap[key] != null) {
                ownedMap[key]?.add(item)
            } else {
                ownedMap[key] = mutableListOf(item)
            }
        } else {
            if (unOwnedMap[key] != null) {
                unOwnedMap[key]?.add(item)
            } else {
                unOwnedMap[key] = mutableListOf(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a few words to explain what your code does so that it helps people to understand what is happening?

Comment: First, we create two maps where we will add the resulting sorted values.
After that, we iterate over the sourceMap. SourceMap contains values in the form String, MutableList<Item>. Next, we iterate over the list of items. And if the item has an owned parameter with value true, we add that item to ownedMap, otherwise to unOwnedMap.